# Magento 2.36 - How to sort printout of Invoice, Shipments and Credit Memos based on custom filter on SKU column/field?

Tags: magento2, php

The items in printout of the **invoices**, **shipments** and **credit memos** are sorted by sequences as to when they are **added in the order**. My question is how do I go about sorting them. For example how do I go about sorting them based on SKU column.

Scenario is that I have a long list of products in our Magento 2.36 store. In which each product's SKU is compromised of **9 integers**.

Case in point: 106110152, 106110163, 106110203, 106110172, etc.

I want to be able to sort based on **the last digit of each items SKU number**.

| Product | SKU |
| --- | --- |
| Product with last digit 2 | 106110152 |
| Product with last digit also 2 | 106110172 |
| Product with last digit 3 | 106110163 |
| Product with last digit also 3 | 106110203 |

I have been trying and playing with **invoice.php** and figured out I have to do something with:

```
            /* Add body */
        foreach ($invoice->getAllItems() as $item) {
            if ($item->getOrderItem()->getParentItem()) {
                continue;
            }
            /* Draw item */
            $this->_drawItem($item, $page, $order);
            $page = end($pdf->pages);
        }
```

Any comments, suggestions, etc would be a massive help.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out how to tackle this problem. BTW I have installed a 3rd party module called FOOMAN\PrintOrderPDF (for printing the order list!) and modified on top of it. This is just for testing purposes for now. The logic is the same to modify the Invoice, Shipping and Credit Memos.

Modify:

```
        foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
            if ($item->getParentItem()) {
                continue;
            }
```

with this:

```
       $_sortedItems = array();

       foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
           $_sortedItems[$item->getSKU()] = $item;
        }

        function my_sort($a,$b)
        {
            if (($a->getSKU()) == ($b->getSKU())) {
                return 0;
            }

            return (($a->getSKU()%10) < ($b->getSKU()%10)) ? -1 : 1;
        } 
        usort($_sortedItems, "Fooman\PrintOrderPdf\Model\Pdf\my_sort");

        foreach ($_sortedItems as $item) {
            if ($item->getParentItem()) {
                continue;
            }
```

Posting this as "if someone is facing the same problem" and needs inspiration!